# How to apply conditions when accessing records using a has_many through relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :campaign_keywords
  has_many   :leads, :through => :campaign_keywords
end

class CampaignKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  has_many   :leads
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign_keyword
end
```

I am trying to build a function in the "Campaign" model that will only return leads which belong to a given campaign_keyword.

My attempt is:

```
def leads?(campaign_keyword_id = -1)
  self.leads :conditions => ['campaign_keyword_id = #{campaign_keyword_id}']
end
```

but this does not work, the conditions are ignored.

Can you see a solution to this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you adding this method to the Campaign model when it has nothing to do with Campaign? Why can't you just do `campaign_keyword.leads` using the existing association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) for your `Lead` model, like so:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign_keyword

  named_scope :with_keyword, lambda { |keyword| { :conditions => { :campaign_keyword => keyword } } }
end
```

Now, when you want to get leads for a particular campaign keyword, you would do so like this:

```
def leads_for_campaign(keyword)
  self.leads.with_keyword(keyword)
end
```

This is much nicer and more re-usable, because the Lead model itself now knows how to find leads for a specific campaign.

For more of an idea of what you can do with named_scopes, check out http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def leads?(campaign_keyword_id = -1)
  self.leads.all :conditions => ['campaign_keyword_id = #{campaign_keyword_id}']
end
```

I would rewrite your query as follows:

```
def leads?(campaign_keyword_id = -1)
  self.leads.all :conditions => ['campaign_keyword_id = ?', campaign_keyword_id]
end
```

OR

```
self.leads.find_all_by_compaign_keyword_id(campaign_keyword_id)
```

Comment: Its still ignoring the :conditions arguments.

SQL generated is:

SELECT `leads`.* FROM `leads` INNER JOIN `campaign_keywords` ON `leads`.campaign_keyword_id = `campaign_keywords`.id WHERE ((`campaign_keywords`.campaign_id = 1))

Comment: Did you try the second option?